# gazebo UDRF tutorial dies

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I'm following the tutorial here,

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf

and running,

roslaunch rrbot_description rrbot_rviz.launch

I can see the robot in rviz and the window with the sliders, but the sliders don't do anything, and rviz shows errors that there are no tf transforms.   Is this a bug in the tutorial or the git code, or could anything be wrong with my setup?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216165/gazebo-udrf-tutorial-dies/) by [charles.fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/22231/charles.fox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2015-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answering own question for future reference -- it started working when I restarted roscore and relaunched, possibly due to an old Gazebo run having left some messages or nodes active.

---

Originally posted by [charles.fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/22231/charles.fox/) with karma: 120 on 2015-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0